# SMO objects don't execute methods

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2012-r2

I am writing script that is intended to check server version numbers and platforms as part of a server delivery QA check.

The intent is to check for any versions higher than 2008 r2 SP1 and Standard or Enterprise editions only. The results, pass or fail, should eventually write to a log, but I'm not that far yet.

The code below runs as expected on windows 2008 and SQLServer 2008 after adding the snap ins for the SQL provider and commandets.

```
[Version]$gtVersion = "10.50.2500.0"

$server = Get-ChildItem SQLSERVER:\sql\$env:Computername


try {
IF($server){


    switch ($server.Version.Major)
        {
            10 {$versionName = "SQl Server 2008"}
            11 {$versionName = "SQl Server 2012"}
            12 {$versionName = "SQl Server 2014"}
        }

    $currentVersionString = "Current Version is $versionName $($server.ProductLevel) $($server.Edition) $($server.Version.ToString()):"


    switch ($server.Edition)
        {
            "Standard Edition (64-bit)" {break}
            "Enterprise Edition (64-bit)" {break}
            default {Throw "$currentVersionString Invalid Edition"}
        }


     switch -regex ($server.Version.CompareTo($gtVersion))
        {
             "0|[^-]1" {"$currentVersionString OK";break}
             default {"$currentVersionString Too Low"}
        }
} ELSE {Throw "Could not find current SQL Server version number"}
} catch [System.Exception] {$_.Exception.Message}
```

But if I run this same code after importing the SQLPS module on Windows 2012 and SQLServer 2014, the code doesn't work.

The switch statement that checks for the edition name always hits the default and throws the error, even though running the comparison in an IF statement like below works properly

```
IF($server.Edition -eq "Enterprise Edition (64-bit)") {"Editions Match"}
```

The $server.Version.CompareTo() method also doesn't work. It always throws "Cannot find an overload for "CompareTo" and the argument count: "1"."

This is despite the output of $server.Version | Get-Member including the line:

```
TypeName: System.Version

Name          MemberType Definition                                                                                                      
----          ---------- ----------                                                                                             
Clone         Method     System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()                                                         
CompareTo     Method     int CompareTo(System.Object version), int CompareTo(version value), int IComparable.CompareTo(System.Object o...
```

Comparing the version numbers directly works fine:

```
$server.version.Major -ge $gtVersion.Major #returns true
$server.version.Minor -ge $gtVersion.Minor #returns false
```

$server.Version.ToString() doesn't work either. It just returns an empty string object, even though $server.Version returns the below output to the host:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
12     0      2000   -1
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work fine here, except for one thing. You forgot the `break` in the second `switch` statement. The second regex should not be a character class, just a straight up match.

```
switch -regex ($server.Version.CompareTo($gtVersion))
    {
         "[0-1]" {"$currentVersionString OK"; break;}
         "-1"  {"$currentVersionString Too Low"; break; }
    }
```

Alternative to switch:

```
if($Server.Version.CompareTo($gtVersion) -ge 0) {
    "$currentVersionString OK"
} else {
    "$currentVersionString Too Low"
}
```

Comment: Do I need a break if the list is exhaustive? The CompareTo() method can only return -1,0, or 1 right?

Comment: Well, yes and no. The break ensures it doesn't fall-through. On the other your second regex is incorrect. I've corrected it in my code.

Comment: Thanks for the regex fix. Clearly thats not my strong suit. And you're right that I did need that break. I don't know why I remembered it in the first switch and not the second.

Comment: Turns out regex doesn't like the -1 either. I changed my code in the post. The regex is probably more trouble an it's worth at this point. I just didn't want to have to have two cases with the same result.

Comment: I actually hate the powershell `switch` statement. It's unpredictable, buggy, and breaks in the debugger.